# Extracting a string of words from a string vector data

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a string vector data as shown below

```
Data
Posted by Mohit Garg on May 7, 2016
Posted by Dr. Lokesh Garg on April 8, 2018
Posted by Lokesh.G.S  on June 11, 2001
Posted by Mohit.G.S. on July 23, 2005
Posted by Dr.Mohit G Kumar Saha on August 2, 2019
```

I have used str_extract() function  as

```
str_extract(Data, "Posted by \\w+. \\w+ \\w+")
```

It generated the output as

```
[1] "Posted by Mohit Garg on"   "Posted by Dr. Lokesh Garg" NA                         
[4] NA                          NA
```

I want the output should like

```
[1] "Posted by Mohit Garg on"   "Posted by Dr. Lokesh Garg"  "Posted by Lokesh.G.S"                       
[4] "Posted by Mohit.G.S."                     "Posted by Dr.Mohit G Kumar Saha"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can try :

```
stringr::str_extract(df$Data, "Posted by .+?(?=\\s+on)")

#[1] "Posted by Mohit Garg" "Posted by Dr. Lokesh Garg"  "Posted by Lokesh.G.S"
#[4] "Posted by Mohit.G.S." "Posted by Dr.Mohit G Kumar Saha"
```

This extracts everything from `"Posted by"` till `"on"` excluding `"on"`.

---

Same in base R :

```
sub(".*(Posted by .+?)(?=\\s+on).*", '\\1', df$Data, perl = TRUE)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Data = c("Posted by Mohit Garg on May 7, 2016", 
"Posted by Dr. Lokesh Garg on April 8, 2018", "Posted by Lokesh.G.S  on June 11, 2001", 
"Posted by Mohit.G.S. on July 23, 2005", "Posted by Dr.Mohit G Kumar Saha on August 2, 2019"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: It is generating the output up to "on"

Comment: I dont want "on" in the final output. Deleting "on" in such a way that , it doesn't effect if the name has "on"

Comment: @djMohit Do you mean `stringr::str_extract(df$Data, "Posted by .+?(?=\\bon\\b)")` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sub` and remove `on` and everything after it with `*on.*`.

```
sub(" +?on.*$", "", Data)
#[1] "Posted by momon"                 "Posted by on Mohit Garg"        
#[3] "Posted by Dr. Lokesh Garg"       "Posted by Lokesh.G.S"           
#[5] "Posted by Mohit.G.S."            "Posted by Dr.Mohit G Kumar Saha"
```

Or with `perl = TRUE`

```
sub("(.*) +on.*", "\\1", Data, perl = TRUE)
```

Data:

```
Data <- c("Posted by momon on Monday 29 Feb 2020"
, "Posted by on Mohit Garg on May 7, 2016"
, "Posted by Dr. Lokesh Garg on April 8, 2018"
, "Posted by Lokesh.G.S  on June 11, 2001"
, "Posted by Mohit.G.S. on July 23, 2005"
, "Posted by Dr.Mohit G Kumar Saha on August 2, 2019")
```

Have a look at [R regex compiler working differently for the given regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62019141/10488504).

Comment: This will delete "on" from the name if a name contains "on".. I  want  to remove "on" from the end only

Comment: Now it should take the last on.

Comment: Using `sub(" +?on.*$", "", Data)` on `Data <- c("Posted by Ona'je Monday on 29 Feb 2020", "Posted by Ondrej on 29 Feb 2020")` gives me `"Posted by Ona'je Monday" "Posted by Ondrej"` what is what I would have expected when removing everything after the last `on`.

Comment: Using `sub(" +?on.*$", "", Data)` on `Data <- c("Posted by ondrej on 29 Feb 2020")` gives me `"Posted by ondrej"`, what I would have expected when removing everything after the last `on`.