# R regular expression: isolate parenthesized suffix

Tags: r, regex

I'm using regular expressions in R. I am trying to pick out parenthesized content that is at the end of some strings in a character vector.  I'm able to find parenthesized content when it exists, but I'm failing to excluded non-parenthesized content in inputs that don't have parens.

Example:

```
> x <- c("DECIMAL", "DECIMAL(14,5)", "RAND(1)")
> gsub("(.*?)(\\(.*\\))", "\\2", x)
[1] "DECIMAL" "(14,5)"  "(1)"
```

The last 2 elements in output are correct, the first one is not. I want

```
c("", "(14,5)", "(1)")
```

The input can have anything, literally any word or number characters, before the parenthesized content.

Comment: `regmatches(x, gregexpr("([(].*?[)])", x))`

Comment: @EyayawB. Clever. Returns a list, not a vector, but can clean up easily enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
sub("^.*?(\\(.*\\))?$", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T7XfZf/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars (since it is a PCRE regex, see `perl=TRUE`) as few as possible
- `(\\(.*\\))?` - an optional Group 1: a `(`, then any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, and then a `)`
- `$` - end of string.

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/doGWQT):

```r
x <- c("DECIMAL", "DECIMAL(14,5)", "RAND(1)")
sub("^.*?(\\(.*\\))?$", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] ""       "(14,5)" "(1)"
```

**NOTE**: `perl=TRUE` is very important in this case because the two parts in the regex have quantifiers of different greediness.

Comment: I missed the `perl=TRUE` part while I was trying to solve on my own.  That is the critical part! Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @pauljohn32 Yes, that is really crazy about the TRE regex, you may read more on that in [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62021015/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract` or `regmatches`

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
replace_na(str_extract(x, "\\([^)]+\\)"), "")
#[1] ""       "(14,5)" "(1)"
```

---

With `sub/gsub` if the pattern is not matched, it returns the whole string

Comment: I trust it works. I don't want install tidyverse just for this purpose.  I'm avoiding it wherever possible.